# Limitar cantidad de opciones seleccionables en un <select multiple>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este select múltiple:

```html
<select multiple="" class="form-control" name="evaluador[]" id="evaluador">
<option value="1">Casa</option>
<option value="2">Apartamento</option>
<option value="2">Finca</option>                           
</select>
```

Lo que necesito es que solamente me permita seleccionar dos de las opciones que se muestran para enviarlo a una base de datos.

Comment: serias tan amable de pegar el codigoque llevas @hector Ariza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con jQuery:

```js
$("select#evaluador").change(function () {
  if($("select#evaluador option:selected").length > 2) {
    //tu código aquí
   }
});
```

Esto limitará a 2 las opciones a seleccionar.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, lo probaré muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Algo que puedes hacer es crear un controlador de JavaScript que lleve una cuenta de la última opción válida y si se elige una opción inválida (p.e. elegir más de 2 valores), entonces que se vuelva a la última opción válida.

Algo como esto:

```js
var ultimoValorValido = null;
$("#evaluador").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#evaluador option:checked").length > 2) {
    $("#evaluador").val(ultimoValorValido);
  } else {
    ultimoValorValido = $("#evaluador").val();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple="" class="form-control" name="evaluador[]" id="evaluador">
  <option value="1">Casa</option>
  <option value="2">Apartamaento</option>
  <option value="3">Finca</option>
  <option value="4">Finca 2</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, lo probaré muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola esto me funciono bien.

```
    $("#evaluador").on('change', function(e) {
        if (Object.keys($(this).val()).length > 2) {
            $('option[value="' + $(this).val().toString().split(',')[2] + '"]').prop('selected', false);
        }
    });
```

Lo que hace es que al evento de cambio del select le vamos a permitir solo 2 opciones, cuando se marca la 3ra, se desmarca inmediatamente, asicional a esto, también se podría lanzar un mensaje con la advertencia.

Answer (score -1):

traes la informacion que vas a meter al select de la base de datos

ejemplo aca el modelo logica

```
public function listar(){
        $datos = array();
        $consulta="SELECT * FROM tblProductos p inner join tblSubcategorias s on p.idSubcategoria=s.idSubcategoria inner join tblCategorias c on c.idCategoria=s.idCategoria";
        $resultado = $this->conexion->query($consulta);
        while ($filaTmp = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $datos [] = $filaTmp;
        }
        if($resultado){
            return $datos;
        }
        elseif (!$this->conexion->query($consulta)) {
            echo $this->conexion->errno . " : " . $this->conexion->error . "\n";
        }
    }
```

controlador enviar los datos a la vista

```
require_once("../../model/productos.php");
                $varProductos= new productos();
                $productos = $varProductos->listar();
```

haces el recorrido en el option

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label class="control-label">Productos</label>
          <select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" name="producto[]" multiple data-error="Es un campo obligatorio" data-live-search="true" required="required">
          <?php 
          foreach ($productos $producto){                              
          echo '<option value="'.$producto['idProducto'].'">'.$producto['producto'].'</option>';
          ?>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
          </select>
          <div class="help-block with-errors">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Y cómo hago para que sólo me seleccione sólo dos elementos de select multiple por jquery o por javascript ya que necesito es que a partir de las dos selecciones que anteriormente seleccioné, valga la redundancia, guardarla en la base de datos.

Comment: el select multiple tiene la opcion de marcar y desmarcar la seleccion.  con la etiqueta name="producto[]" aqui estas metiendo lo que vas   a mandar seria un arreglo

Comment: si te sirvio mi ayuda regalame +1 jeje me avisas si puedes

Comment: Tu respuesta no responde la pregunta, que por cierto es bastante clara.
**Lo que necesito es que sólo me permite seleccionar dos de las opciones que se muestran para enviarlo a una base de datos. Gracias**

Comment: select multiple es la respuesta como enviarlo accedes al name="datos[ ]" con jquery y listo

Comment: Por favor, tomate el tiempo de leer otra vez:

**Lo que necesito es que sólo me permite seleccionar dos de las opciones**

Comment: bueno se hizo el intento saludos